# PHP rawurlencode path with spaces fails with can't find file

Tags: php, urlencode

I have a file path like this:

`/example/img/letter_images/Chapter 2          The Heller Family`

with subfolders named `Letter #1` etc. When I try to display an image in that folder using:

```
<?php
class struct
{
    public static function imageDisplayGallery($img_folder_path)
    {

        $index=0;
        foreach(glob("$img_folder_path*/*_thumb.jpg") as $thumb)
        {
            $full=str_replace("_thumb","",$thumb);
            //echo "$full-$thumb";

            echo '<a href="',rawurlencode($full),'" class="photo-link smoothbox" rel="gallery"><img src="',rawurlencode($thumb),'" /></a>';
            $index=$index+1;

            if($index % 6 == 0)
            {
                echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
                $index=0;
            }
        }
    }
}

$images=struct::imageDisplayGallery('img/letter_images/Chapter 2          The Heller Family/');
?>
```

I get an error in console that says:

```
http://www.example.com/img%2Fletter_images%2FChapter%202%20%20%20%…%20%20%20%20The%20Heller%20Family%2FLetter%20%23%209%2Fpfr100350_thumb.jpg
```

not found. Can someone explain why this could be?

when I use just `urlencode` I get `+` instead of a space (which is obviously wrong). What else could I try to troubleshoot this?

Comment: The examples don't match the error, where's the folder name in the link ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Thanks for that- I omitted a necessary bit of code when I was trying to make my example simpler

Comment: it encodes the slash `/`. replace `%2F` with `/`

Comment: @Deadooshka that fixed my issue. If you will post it as an answer I will accept it